# "Unable to cast value to Object" error message

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am using a remote function, as seen at the end, and for some reason, a normal assignment of a variable won't work, it is giving me the error message, "Unable to cast value to Object," what is wrong?

```
local storeEvent = script.Parent.Parent.OpenStore
local slotNum = 1
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function (hit)
    if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
        storeEvent:InvokeClient(slotNum)
    end
end)
```

and connecting to the other script:

```
script.Parent.OnInvoke:Connect(function (slot)
    local StoreArrows = game.ReplicatedStorage.StoreArrows
    StoreArrows.SlotNum.Value = slot
    local cam = game.Workspace.Camera
    local storeButtons = script.Parent
    local camNum = game.ReplicatedStorage.StoreArrows.CamNum.Value
    local camNumInst = game.Workspace.CamStorage:WaitForChild("Cam-"..camNum)
    cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    cam.CFrame = camNumInst.CFrame
    local clonedStoreButtons = StoreArrows:Clone()
    clonedStoreButtons.Parent = player.PlayerGui.ScreenGui
end)
```

Comment: What is the line that the error is pointing at?

Comment: line 5 of the sending script

Comment: I think it's a scope issue.  Put that line at the beginning of your second script, and define that variable outside of the function.  `local storeButtons = script.Parent     storeButtons.OnInvoke:Connect(function (slot)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that many clients connect to a server at a time. So when you call a [RemoteEvent's InvokeClient](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteFunction/InvokeClient) function, you have to tell it *which* client to invoke it on. The first parameter to `InvokeClient` is supposed to be the player, that's why the error is telling you that it cannot cast the `slotNum` value to a player object.

```
local storeEvent = script.Parent.Parent.OpenStore
local slotNum = 1
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    -- check that the thing that we touched is actually a player
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if player then
        -- tell that player to open the store
        storeEvent:InvokeClient(player, slotNum)
    end
end)
```

Comment: i tried that just now, and now it just doesn't do anything

Comment: I see you marked this as the answer even though you said it doesn't work. Did you solve your problem with the connecting script?

Comment: yes, it helped, I have now found the problem, the Remote Event wasn't stored within the Replicated Storage it now works properly